# Navigating to Intercepted Routes in Next.js 13 without Hard Refresh

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I'm working on a Next.js application where I have implemented the Intercepting Routes feature. I have a directory structure in the app directory that looks like this:

```
/news/[id]/page.jsx

/@modal/(.)news/[id]/page.jsx
```

The behavior I desire is as follows:

- Modal Preview: Clicking on a news card intercepts the current route and displays a brief preview of the news content in a modal.
- Navigate to News Page: I want to provide an option for users (through a maximizing button or a choice at the start) to navigate to the full news page without triggering a hard page refresh or the modal again.

However, when I try to navigate to the full news page using methods like `router.push()` when the modal is already open, it triggers the modal again or not working at all. Utilizing `<a>` tag or `window.location.reload()`, on the other hand, results in a hard refresh.

**UPDATE:**

I've created a working example based on Vercel’s Nextgram demo to illustrate my issue: https://wk6x5c-3000.csb.app/

In this modified version, each image has two links: "Modal" and "Navigate to Page". Clicking "Modal" opens a preview and updates the URL to /news/id as expected. However, I want users to be able to click "Navigate to Page" or "Read the Full Story" to go to the full content page with the same URL structure (/news/id), but without causing a hard refresh – which is currently happening because I'm using an `<a>` tag.

The point of my question is: Can we use the same URL route for both a modal and a full-page view in Next.js, allowing users to choose between a brief preview (modal) and the full content page, without requiring a hard refresh?

I appreciate any insights or suggestions on this issue.

Comment: Great question. Did you happen to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a working example?

Do you want to have the `/news/page.jsx` page provide a card that when clicked opens either:

- a modal `/@modal/(.)news/[id]/page.jsx`
  or:
- links you to a `/news/[id]/page.jsx`

With a modal, you can, after intercepting, do this to get back:

```
const router = useRouter()

  const onDismiss = useCallback(() => {
    router.back()
  }, [router])
```

at the `/@modal/(.)news/[id]/page.jsx` you can render this:

```
<Modal>
   <NewsPreview data={data} />
</Modal>
```

at `/news/page.jsx` where you render all news, you can use next `<Link>` with a `href={id}` for each of the news.

In your `layout.jsx` you can conditionally render either the `@modal` slot or create a new `@news` slot if you want to render something else. (I suppose you can use the already included `props.children` from `/news/[id]/page.jsx` in your layout.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. I've updated my original question with a working example to better illustrate the issues I'm encountering. You can check it out here : [link](https://wk6x5c-3000.csb.app)